# Atata iframe SwitchTo method compile error : Using generic type requires 1 type argument

Tags: c#, automated-tests, ui-automation, atata

I have created a Frame control - `Frame1` under `Class1`:

```
public Frame<_> Frame1 { get; private set; }
```

And defined `Class2` for frame page:

```
public class Class2<TPage> : Page<TPage> where TPage : Page<TPage>
```

When I call `Frame1.SwitchTo<Class2>()` I get a compile error:

> Using generic type  requires 1 type argument

Is there any way to resolve this?

I am defining `Class2` as above as I want to define other classes inheriting `Class2`.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Class2` page object type is a generic base page object, then it cannot be passed directly to `SwitchTo` method. You can pass only complete classes. For example you can create non-generic `Class2` and pass it.

```
// Base page object.
public class Class2<TOwner> : Page<TOwner> where TOwner : Class2<TOwner>
{
}

public class Class2 : Class2<Class2>
{
}

public class AnotherClass2 : Class2<AnotherClass2>
{
}
```

This will allow you to pass `Class2` to `SwitchTo` method:

```
Frame1.SwitchTo<Class2>()
```

or

```
Frame1.SwitchTo<AnotherClass2>()
```